# Isn't it redundant for Control.Lens.Setter to wrap types in functors?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm watching the `Control.Lens` introduction [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cefnmjtAolY).
It makes me wonder why is it needed for the `Setter` type to wrap things in functors.
It's (roughly) defined like this:

```
type Control.Lens.Setter s t a b = (Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f t
```

Let's say I have a data called `Point` that's defined like this:

```
data Point = Point { _x :: Int, _y :: Int } deriving Show
```

Then I can write my own `xlens` like this:

```
type MySetter s t a b = (a -> b) -> s -> t
xlens :: MySetter Point Point Int Int
xlens f p = p { _x = f (_x p) }
```

And I can use it like this:

```
p = Point 100 200
xlens (+1) p -- Results in Point { _x = 101, _y = 200 }
```

By using `Control.Lens`, the same effect is achieved by:

```
over x (+1) p
```

where the following stands:

```
x :: Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> Point -> f Point
over :: Setter Point Point Int Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Point -> Point
```

So my question is, since the same effect can be achieved in a simpler manner, why `Control.Lens` wraps things in functors? It looks redundant to me, since my `xlens` does the same as `Control.Lens`'s `over x`.

Just for the record, I can also chain my lenses in the same manner:

```
data Atom = Atom { _element :: String, _pos :: Point } deriving Show
poslens :: MySetter Atom Atom Point Point
poslens f a = a { _pos = f (_pos a) }

a = Atom "Oxygen" p
(poslens . xlens) :: (Int -> Int) -> Atom -> Atom
(poslens . xlens) (+1) a -- Results in Atom "Oxygen" (Point 101 200)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a wonderful question and will require a little bit of unpacking.

I want to gently correct you on one point right off the bat: the type of Setter in the `lens` package as of recent versions is

```
type Setter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
```

No `Functor` in sight ... yet.

That does not invalidate your question however. Why isn't the type simply

```
type Setter s t a b = (a -> b) -> s -> t
```

For that we first have to talk about `Lens`.

### Lens

A `Lens` is a type that allows us to perform both a getter and a setter operation. These two combined form one beautiful functional reference.

A simple pick for `Lens` type is:

```
type Getter s a = s -> a
type Setter s t a b = (a -> b) -> s -> t
type Lens s t a b = (Getter s a, Setter s t a b)
```

This type however is deeply unsatisfying.

- It fails to compose with `.`, which is perhaps the single best selling point of the `lens` package.
- It is rather memory inefficient to build lots of tuples, only to rip them apart later.
- The big one: functions that take getters (like `view`) and setters (like `over`) cannot take lenses because their types are so different.

Without that last problem solved why even bother writing a library? We would hate for users to have to constantly think about where they are in the UML hierarchy of optics, adjusting their function calls each time they move up or down.

The question of the moment is then: is there a type we can write down for `Lens` such that it is *automatically* both a `Getter` and a `Setter`? And for that we have to transform the types of `Getter` and `Setter`.

### Getter

- First note that `s -> a` is equivalent to `forall r. (a -> r) -> s -> r`. This transformation into continuation passing style is far from obvious. You might be able to intuit this transformation as this: "A function of type `s -> a` is a promise that given any `s` you can hand me an `a`. But that should be equivalent to the promise that given a function that maps `a` to `r` you can hand me a function that maps `s` to `r` also." Maybe? Maybe not. There might be a leap of faith involved here.
- Now define `newtype Const r a = Const r deriving Functor`. Note that `Const r a` is the same as `r`, mathematically and at runtime.
- Now note that `type Getter s a = forall r. (a -> r) -> s -> r` can be rewritten as `type Getter s t a b = forall r. (a -> Const r b) -> s -> Const r t`. Though we introduced new type variables and mental anguish for ourselves this type is still mathematically identical to what we started out with (`s -> a`).

### Setter

- Define `newtype Identity a = Identity a`. Note that `Identity a` is the same as `a`, mathematically and at runtime.
- Now note that `type Setter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t` is still identical to the type that we started out with.

### All together

With this paperwork out of the way, can we unify setters and getters into one single `Lens` type?

```
type Setter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
type Getter s t a b = forall r. (a -> Const r b) -> s -> Const r t
```

Well this is Haskell and we can abstract out the choice of `Identity` or `Const` to a quantified variable. As [the lens wiki says](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Derivation), all that `Const` and `Identity` have in common is that each is a `Functor`. We then choose that as a sort of point of unification for these types:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

(There are other reasons to choose `Functor` too, such as to prove the laws of functional references by using free theorems. But we will handwave a little bit here for time.) That `forall f` is like the `forall r`. above – it lets consumers of the type choose how to fill the variable in. Fill in an `Identity` and you get a setter. Fill in a `Const a` and you get a getter. It was by choosing small and careful transformations along the way that we were able to arrive at this point.

### Caveats

It might be important to note that this derivation is *not* the original motivation for the `lens` package. As the [Derivation wiki page states](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Derivation) explains, you can start from the interesting behavior of `(.)` with certain functions and tease out optics from there. But I think this path we carved out is a little better at explaining the question you posed, which was a big question I had starting out too. I also want to refer you to [lens over tea](https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-1), which provides yet *another* derivation.

I think these multiple derivations are a good thing and a kind of dipstick for the healthiness of the `lens` design. That we are able to arrive at the same elegant solution from different angles means that this abstraction is robust and well-supported by different intuitions and mathematics.

I also lied a little bit about the type of Setter in recent `lens`. It's actually

```
type Setter s t a b = forall f. Settable f => (a -> f b) -> s -> t b
```

This is another example of abstracting the higher-order type in optical types to provide the library user a better experience. Almost always `f` will be instantiated to `Identity`, as there is an `instance Settable Identity`. However every now and then you might want to pass setters to the `backwards` function, which fixes `f` to be `Backwards Identity`. We can probably categorize this paragraph as "more information about `lens` than you probably wanted to know."

Answer (score 6):

In a sense, the reason `lens` wraps setters in functor-returns is that they would be *too powerful* otherwise.

In fact, when a setter is *used*, the functor will be instantiated to `Identity` anyway, which is exactly like your proposed signature. However, *the implementation of a setter must not exploit this fact*. With your signature, I could write something like

```
zlens :: MySetter Point Point Int Int
zlens _f p = p  -- no z here!
```

Well, this is just not possible with the `Functor` based signature, because `zlens` would need to be universally quantified over the functor it could not know how to inject a result into the `f` wrapper. The only way to get a result of the functor type is to first apply the setter-function to a field of the right type!

So, this is just a nice free theorem<sup>†</sup>.

More practically, we need the functor wrapper for *compatibility*. While you can define *setters* without this wrapper, this is not possible for getters, as these use `Const` rather than `Identity`, and need the added polymorphism in the first argument of this type constructor. By requiring such a wrapper for *all* lens flavours (only with different class constraints), we can use the same combinators for all of them, yet the type system will always collapse the functionality down to whichever features are actually applicable to the situation.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Thinking about it, the guarantee is actually not very strong... I can still subvert it with some `fmap (const old)` cheatery, but it's certainly not something that could realistically happen by mistake.</sub>

Comment: Can you please explain in greater details why wrapping a type inside a functor would prevent that? I can always do the exact same thing, even if a type is wrapped: `zlens f p = fmap (const p) $ f 0 -- zlens :: Lens' Point Int`.

Comment: @qwe hence my footnote. But at least, with the wrapper you must apply the provided function to some value of the right type.

Comment: Then I guess I'm still not convinced it's necessary. Could it be something concerning monads and side effect computations?

Comment: I don't think you can cheat your way around it if you make a *type-changing* `Setter`. But of course those aren't always available.