# Why does Setter have Traversable constraint?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

When you look at [`setting`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-core-2.1.2/docs/Lens-Family-Unchecked.html#v:setting) in `lens-family-core` package, you'll find that its type is `Identical f => ((a -> b) -> s -> t) -> LensLike f s t a b`, and `Identical` is defined as `class (Traversable f, Applicative f) => Identical f`.

I understand it needs `Applicative` and `Identical` as it uses `pure` and `extract`, but I'm not sure why it needs `Traversable`.

```
setting :: Identical f => ((a -> b) -> s -> t) -> LensLike f s t a b
setting sec f = pure . sec (extract . f)
```

I also found that [`Setter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#t:Setter) in `lens` package had `Traversable` constraint through [`Settable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#t:Settable). So I guess a setter needs `Traversable` in general.

Why does a setter need `Traversable` in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setters don't really need `Traversable`, but effectively you enforce having this constraint anyway because `Identical` / `Settable` are classes that only allows trivial instances. I.e., either `Identity` or something isomorphic to it, and all of these are obviously traversable as well.

Notice you could always write

```
idenTraverse :: (Identical t, Applicative g) => (a -> g b) -> t a -> g (t b)
idenTraverse f = fmap pure . f . extract
```

which is equivalent to the standard `traverse`. (Actually this needs only `Functor g`, incidentally.)

Explicitly requiring the standard `Traversable` interface makes for a cleaner, more consistent hierarchy, without actually changing what you can or can't do with the setters.

Answer (score 4):

Instances of both [`Settable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Internal-Setter.html) from *lens* and [`Identical`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-core-2.1.2/docs/Lens-Family-Unchecked.html#t:Identical) from *lens-family* must be isomorphic to `Identity`. (On why that must be so, see [hao's answer to *Isn't it redundant for Control.Lens.Setter to wrap types in functors?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37667560/2751851) , and in particular the caveat at the very end of it.) Now, if our goal were merely to make sure a functor is isomorphic to `Identity`, we wouldn't necessarily have to set up a brand new class *just* for that purpose, as the following constraint would suffice:

```
type Setter s t a b = forall f. (Distributive f, Lone f) => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Here, `Lone` is a subclass of `Traversable` for functors which hold exactly one value, which doesn't rely on `Applicative`:

```
class Traversable f => Lone f where
    sequenceL :: Functor m => f (m a) -> m (f a)
    traverseL :: Functor m => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m (f b)
```

[`Distributive` functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html) are isomorphic to functions, and `Lone` functors are isomorphic to pairs. If a functor is both `Distributive` and `Lone`, it must be isomorphic to a function functor and to a pair functor. That is only possible if the argument type of the function and the fixed-type component of the pair are both (isomorphic to) `()`, which in turn means the functor must be isomorphic to `Identity`.

Arranging the constraint for `Setter` in this way wouldn't have been alien to the style of optics type synonyms seen in *lens*. In fact, it would be reminiscent of how [`Getter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#t:Getter) relies on the combination of `Functor` and `Contravariant` to ensure the functor it uses is phantom on its argument. One inconvenience, however, is there is no canonical implementation of `Lone` in the ecosystem. Since *lens* would have to define the class anyway, it might as well set up a special purpose class like `Settable` instead, which in any case has the advantage of making signatures and type errors slightly more self-explanatory.

Given that `Settable` is ultimately a stand-in for the combination of `Distributive` and `Lone`, it makes sense to make it a subclass of `Distributive` and `Traversable`. Doing so delineates the provenance of the class, with `Lone` being just one further restriction away from `Traversable`. While *lens-family-core* omits the `Distributive` constraint (presumably to avoid depending on the *distributive* package), we can sense a similar motivation from a comment to [the definition of `Identical`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family-core-2.1.2/docs/src/Lens.Family.Identical.html#Identical):

> ```
> -- It would really be much better if comonads was in tranformers
> class (Traversable f, Applicative f) => Identical f where
>   extract :: f a -> a
> ```

`Lone` functors are all comonads, and adding a `Comonad` superclass to `Identical` in principle would allow not defining `extract` anew, while highlighting a different aspect of what an `Identical` functor is supposed to be like.

A couple notes to wrap things up. Firstly, you may have noticed I haven't mention the `Applicative` constraint at all so far. Even though the constraint is necessary in practice to make `pure` available for the implementation of `setting`, it is in a sense not as essential as the others. Distributive functors are necessarily applicative, and `Distributive` doesn't have `Applicative` as a superclass merely because `(<*>)` is awkward to express in terms of the distributive interface. `pure` itself, on the other hand, can be straightforwardly implemented in its terms:

```
pureD :: Distributive g => a -> g a
pureD = cotraverse getConst . Const
```

Secondly, it is worth mentioning there is a more succinct way to specify that a `Functor` (that is, a **Hask** endofunctor) must be isomorphic to `Identity`: using [the `Adjunction` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4.2/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html) to state it must be adjoint to itself. `Setter`, then, might be made to look like this:

```
type Setter s t a b = forall f. Adjunction f f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

(Incidentally, `Distributive` functors are precisely the right adjoint endofunctors, and `Lone` functors are precisely the left adjoint ones.)

This constraint, however, is far from self-explanatory, and `Adjunction` isn't exactly a class in widespread use, so ditching `Settable` in favour of it doesn't look like a very attractive option.

Comment: You answered most of the questions I planed to ask even before I actually ask them. Thank you!